# Delete line containing pattern found anywhere in another file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I'd like to compare two files and delete lines in file1 if they contain a pattern found anywhere in file2. I did some searching and the closest answers I've been able to find were how to delete lines that appear in another file.

I'd like a simple grep, awk, sed, etc one-liner if possible. I'm matching on IP addresses, as shown below.

file1

```
10.10.50.1 00:00:10:23 0000.0012.3456 Vlan1
10.10.50.2 00:00:12:34 1234.56AB.CDEF Vlan2
10.10.50.3 00:00:23:10 ABCD.EF12.345 Vlan3billion
```

file2

```
these-are some_words 10.10.50.2 andmaybe some-other words
theseare somewords 10.10.50.99 and-maybe some_other words
```

Expected output:

```
10.10.50.1 00:00:10:23 0000.0012.3456 Vlan1
10.10.50.3 00:00:23:10 ABCD.EF12.345 Vlan3billion
```

Comment: What's a *pattern*? A fixed string (sequence of non-blanks taken litterally), a shell pattern (and then, which shell), a regex? This is rather important.

Comment: Define "pattern found anywhere". Are `e som` or `.2 andma` possible patterns? Or could you normalize `file2` to one token per line? (In which case the rest should be trivial.)

Comment: @AlexP I'm completely new to this so I don't know the correct answer to that question. In my case, it's an IP address. Should I reword the question?

Comment: So your real question then is "how do I reduce `file2` to just IP addresses, one per line" and you can take it from there?

Comment: @tripleee I need to remove lines from file1 if they contain IP addresses in file2.

Comment: Do you worry if `1.3.2.1` also matches `121.3.2.124` or is that considered a match, too?

Comment: Thanks for the help tripleee. I need the IPs to match exactly.

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Review [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.
Given the tags you've included, I'd expect to see bash, awk and sed code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly,
you want to exclude from the first file lines that would match any IP address in the second file.

This simple and admittedly a bit lazy solution might be good enough for your purpose:

```
grep -v file1 -Fwf <(awk '{ print $3 }' file2)
```

The Awk extracts the 3rd column with IP addresses,
and `grep` will use those as fixed patterns (`-F`) and only match complete words (`-w`).

If the IP address is not always the 3rd column,
then you could extract them by using pattern matching with `grep`,
as [@tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) suggested:

```
grep -v file1 -Fwf <(grep -owE '[1-9][0-9](\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}' file2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! this works perfectly with the exact example given in my question, but doesn't work in some other situations; such as where I have more words and spaces to the left of the IP addresses in file2.

Comment: @RhythmicUndulations you should include all relevant corner cases that need to be handled. It's impossible to guess what is not included.

Comment: Understood. Some of the words contain underscores and hyphens. I'll update my question.

Comment: The Awk snippet could be replaced with something like `grep -Eo '\<[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}\>' file2` to find IP addresses anywhere in `file2`.

Comment: (The edit you made doesn't really change Awk's idea of what the third field in the fiel is.)

Comment: Thank you tripleee. Sorry, I wasn't understanding how to properly utilize the command you gave. janos' new answer using your input seems to be exactly what I need.

Comment: Thank you janos, this seems to work perfectly so far.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3];next} !($1 in a)' file2 file1

10.10.50.1 00:00:10:23 0000.0012.3456 Vlan1
10.10.50.3 00:00:23:10 ABCD.EF12.345 Vlan3billion
```

Answer (score 0):

More awk ... at the core snaffled from karafka ..

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[gensub(/^.* (([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}) .*$/,"\\1",1,$0)];next} !($1 in a)' file2 file1
10.10.50.1 00:00:10:23 0000.0012.3456 Vlan1
10.10.50.3 00:00:23:10 ABCD.EF12.345 Vlan3billion
```